# How does the heap manager in java or C++ keep track of all the memory locations used by the threads or processes?

Tags: java, c++, memory, operating-system

I wanted to understand what data structures the heap managers in `Java` or OS in case of C++ or C keep track of the memory locations used by the threads and processes. One way is to use a map of objects and the memory address and a reverse map of memory starting address and the size of the object in the memory.
But here it won't be able to cater the new memory requests in `O(1)` time. Is there any better data structure to do this?

Comment: in C++, this is a job for the OS. It isn't specified by the language's standard.

Comment: afaik C++ there is no garbage collection, so C/C++ memory requests can be served by simple system API calls - so you could extend your questions to how OSes manage memory for the different processes.

Comment: There's no garbage collection, but there's still malloc/new and free/delete. That memory must be allocated, so this is a reasonable question. But yes, an OS question if you're not in a managed language.

Answer (score 2):

Note that unmanaged languages are going to be allocating/freeing memory through system calls, generally not managing it themselves. Still regardless of what level of abstraction (OS to the run time), something has to deal with this:

One method is called buddy block allocation, described well with an example on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation). It essentially keeps track of the usage of spaces in memory of varying sizes (typically multiples of 2). This can be done with a number of arrays with clever indexing, or perhaps more intuitively with a binary tree, each node tell whether a certain block is free, all nodes on a level representing the same size block.

This suffers from internal fragmentation; as things come and go, you might ended up with your data scattered rather than being efficiently consolidated, making it harder to fit in large data. This could be countered by a more complicated, [dynamic system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_allocation#Dynamic_memory_allocation), but buddy blocks have the advantage of simplicity.

Comment: You don't want to get the OS involved in most memory allocation operations, the overhead is too high.   We use a buddy system for our parallel langauge PARLANSE, with each thread having its own set of power-of-two-size queues for buddy blocks.  No locks, very small number of  machine instructions to allocate/deallocate a block. Some awkwardness when a block is allocated by one thread, handed by that thread to another, and then deallocated; you can't buddy-system coalesce in this case, because the buddy might not be in the deallocating thread's queues. In general works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

The OS keeps track of the process's memory allocation in an overall view - 4KB pages or bigger "lumps" are stored in some form of list.

In the typical Windows implementation (Microsoft's C runtime library) - at least in recent versions, all memory allocations are done through the HeapAlloc() system call. So every single heap allocation goes through to the OS. Whether the OS actually tracks every single allocation or just keeps a map of "what is free, what is used" is another matter. It is my understanding that the heap management code has no list of "current allocations", just a list of freed memory lump

In Linux/Unix, the C library will typically avoid calling the OS for every little allocation, and instead uses a large lump of memory, and splits that up into smaller pieces per allocation. Again, no tracking of allocated memory inside the heap management.

This is done at a process level. I'm not aware of an operating system that differentiates memory allocations on a per-thread level (other than TLS - thread local storage, but that is typically a very small region, outside of the typical heap code management).

So, in summary: the OS and/or C/C++ runtime doesn't actually keep a list of all the used allocations - it keeps a list of "freed" memory [and when another lump is freed, typically will "Join" previous and next consecutive allocations to reduce fragmentation]. When the allocator is firsts started, it's given a large lump, which is then assigned as a single freed allocation. When a request is made, the lump is split into sections and the free list becomes the remainder. When that lump is not sufficient, another big lump is carved off using the underlying OS allocations.

There is a small amount of metadata stored with each allocation, which contains things like "how much memory is allocated", and this metadata is used when freeing the memory. In the typical case, this data is stored immediately before the allocated memory. But there is no way to find the allocation metadata without knowing about the allocations in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

there is no automatic garbage collection in C++. You need to call free/delete for malloc/new heap memory allocations. That's where tools like valgrind(to check memory leak) comes handy. There are other concepts like auto_ptr which automatically frees the heap memory which you can refer to.

Comment: While true, I think the gist of the question was how the memory is managed and memory locations are kept track of. That needs to be done regardless of what niceness you have in your language.