# Heap pointer register?

Tags: assembly, mips, instruction-set

Many ISAs, such as MIPS, has a register called "stack pointer" to indicate the top of the stack. Why isn't a "heap pointer" register? Does the top of the heap get stored in memory?

Comment: The concept of a "heap" is (generally) managed a step above the CPU. There is no reason to have a "heap pointer" if the CPU does not know it exists. It may not even exist at all in some systems. In such cases, you just have memory in a certain range, and you manage it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't a "heap pointer" register?

There is not a "heap pointer" register, because there is no `malloc` CPU instruction.

The reason there is a "stack pointer" register is because there are CPU instructions which directly manipulate the stack, such as `call`, `push`, and `pop` on x86. These instructions generally mandate the existence of an architectural stack pointer register.

Note: AFAIK there are no such instructions on MIPS; you must adjust the stack pointer yourself to push/pop values, and a "call" saves the return address in the Link Register. Still, the concepts of a call stack and local variables are so central to most all languages, that a register is used to track the stack location, because it is much faster than a memory access.

> Does the top of the heap get stored in memory?

There are lots of different implementations of `malloc`, but they all only take a `size` parameter, there is no option but for `malloc` to keep state in global variables.

Comment: Hmm...for instructions like `store`, which typically takes a register and a memory location as arguments in RISC ISAs, the memory address can be anything in the program's memory space - stack or heap. So in this sense, there are instructions that manipulate the heap, too...

Comment: Or in other words, because the "heap" is not a stack! It doesn't have a "top" or a "bottom". There's no order for storing and retrieving.

Comment: Well yeah, everyting boils down to CPU instructions. But there's a lot more to manipulating the heap than just writing a word to an address. Allocating memory generally involves finding a free block of an appropriate size, and marking it as allocated, likely updating implementation-specific metadata, etc. This is far too complex to be a single CPU instruction.

Comment: Thanks @ Jonathon Reinhart and @Marc.2377. So the OS keeps track of which fragment in the heap is available and which is not. I suppose this "table" (for keeping track) is stored in the memory somewhere? If I'm asking too much - is there a name for this "table"?

Comment: "The heap" is completely implementation-specific and is usually implemented with lists or trees of various types. It's also primarily done in user-space (a library), only requesting additional large blocks of memory to dole out for `malloc` requests.

Comment: @xri Mr. Reinhart is right in that the heap is implementation-specific...the "tree" or whatever means the OS uses to keep track of the heap, the information is stored in *memory* somewhere (there's no dedicated register).

Comment: @xri I don't recall any specific names, but you might benefit from reading on [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [Dynamic Memory Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#Dynamic_memory_allocation) and possibly, [Protected Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode). **Edit** Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17081607/3258851

Comment: Perhaps most importantly, the heap is a shared resource. All threads in a process share the heap. If each thread had its own copy of the heap state, they would corrupt each other. By contrast, each thread has its own stack.